# HAProxy use the old backend

Tags: google-chrome, https, proxy, haproxy

I'm using HAProxy as reverse-proxy for https connections. I have some rules like this:

```
 use_backend server2 if  { req_ssl_sni -i test.domain.com }
```

yesterday i changed a backend for one acl, but somehow some (!!) clients still get the content of the old backend (which is still active for other acls). I can see two different result on the same machine in chrome if one chrome runs in privacy mode.

Restart and reload didn't help.

Comment: Without seeing your full configuration and a reproducible request, it is hard to tell what is wrong. Most likely though you have other rules matching before (remember: the first `use_backend` rule to match wins) or you might still have an old process running which might randomly serve requests. To rule out the latter case, make sure to kill all haproxy processes and start a new one.

Answer (score 0):

It looks that I solved it. I think the Problem was the passthrough via TCP. I change the config to do the SSL Termination by HAProxy and handle it via http. Seems like the rules for TCP / req_ssl_sni were only used for the first connection and bypassed for the following connections even if the hostname changed.